# Is there a debit card that earns miles (1 mile per $1 spent) and doesn't have an annual fee?

Tags: united-states, debit-card, banking, loyalty-programs

I use Bank of America and they offer debit cards on US Airways and Alaska Airlines, but I earn 1 mile for every $2.  Plus, I pay an annual fee.  I would love to switch banks and use a bank that offers a debit card that accrues 1 mile per $1 spent and no annual fee.  I do use my debit card as a credit card for these miles, but the $$ comes right out of my account instead of racking up a credit card debt.

Comment: Would you be open to a credit card that you pay off each month?  It would expand your options a great deal.

Comment: @MrChrister I would!

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is *check* card. It withdraws money from your bank account but is processed through a credit card transaction network, with a signature (unlike a debit card transaction, which takes a PIN). The structure of the fees differs; credit-type transactions have enough fees to offer some rewards back, and debit-type transactions don't. this is also why Ikea gives you a 3% coupon after paying with a debit card: savings vs credit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any that are comparable to credit cards.

There's a reason for that. Debit cards, being newer, [have a much lower interchange rate](http://banking.about.com/od/checkingaccounts/a/debitvscredit.htm). Since collecting on debt is risky and less predictable, rewards / miles are paid from those interchange fees. This means with a debit card there's less money to pay you with.

So what can you do? Assuming your credit isn't terrible, you can just open a credit card account and pay in full for purchases by the grace period. I don't know how all cards work, but my grace period allows me to pay in full by the billing date (roughly a month from purchase) and incur no finance charges. In effect, I get a small 30 day loan with no interest, and a cash back incentive (I dislike miles). You're also less liable for fraud via CC than debit.

Comment: _"You're also less liable for fraud via CC than debit"_ **This is a common myth**. Directly from [Visa's website](http://usa.visa.com/personal/cards/debit/index.html). _Gain peace of mind with Visa's extra security protections.

When you sign for your purchases, your money comes directly from your checking account, but you also get security protections that help prevent, detect and resolve fraud, including:

    * Visa's Zero Liability Policy*, which protects you from unauthorized charges. **Any funds taken from your account due to fraudulent use will be returned to you**._

Comment: "Does not apply to ATM transactions, PIN transactions not processed by Visa, or certain commercial card transactions. Individual provisional credit amounts are provided on a provisional basis and may be withheld, delayed, limited, or rescinded by your issuer based on factors such as gross negligence or fraud, delay in reporting unauthorized use, investigation and verification of claim and account standing and history. You must notify your financial institution immediately of any unauthorized use."

Comment: Also, signatures aren't usually done through the debit network.

Comment: but this doesn't answer the quesiton

Comment: @Larry - "less liable" isn't really the issue, "less risk" is the issue. The risk is that my checking account doesn't have funds while Visa is sorting the problem out. Which is no fun if my card gets stolen and the account gets emptied out just before the mortgage is due. With a CC there's a buffer, the issuer bears the risk -- not me.

Answer (score 0):

I have an American Airlines VISA with miles that has no annual fee, but only because I request that they waive the fee each year. Word to the wise - they've never refused.

Comment: I'm curious if banks will still waive annual fees after the latest round of rule and fee changes.